# Cloud Shellでインストールしたパッケージが消える

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud

App Engine SE for Pythonを使用しており、Cloud Shell上で開発中なのですが、lxmlが入ってないので、 `sudo pip install lxml` でインストールしました。
しかし、数時間立ってCloud Shellを開くとlxmlがおなくなりになっていました。
Cloud on Airでホームディレクトリ配下以外は消える可能性があるとは聞いていたのですが、本当だったのでしょうか？

毎回、 pipでインストールするのは大変なので、

```
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install lxml
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

virtualenvでやってみたのですが、 `No module named lxml` というエラーがでてしまいました。
自分の何が悪いのかよくわかりません。

Comment: 自己解決しました。 ```libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: latest``` をapp.yamlに追加するのを忘れておりました。お手数をおかけしてすみませんでした。

Comment: お疲れ様でした。もしよろしければ、[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)して頂けませんでしょうか？　自己回答後数日待つと、回答を承認することもできるようになります。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。

```
libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: latest
```

をapp.yamlに追加するのを忘れておりました。